# Double cursor in LXDE with python program

Tags: lxde, mouse

I have a python program which connects to a wii remote and moves the mouse or presses keys based on the key presses. If I execute it after boot it works properly. However, I have made it to start on boot after LXDE has started. Then, I get a very weird state where I got 2 pointers. The 2nd "controlled by the wii remote" is fully functional (ie clicks work).

If I use my usb mouse, then the 2nd pointer disappears...until I press buttons on my wii remote again.

Can I fix this, or is this a bug?

Comment: Looks like a similar/same defect has been reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1396361).